# Remove comma in unexected column within csv [awk,sed]

Tags: awk, sed

Is there a simple way to remove a comma within a csv that isn't suppose to be there using AWK/ SED?

The .csv is made up of 5 columns, but that additional comma makes some rows come up with 6 columns. For example see below, the third column i am expecting to be number, but as you can see row 3 and 4 are strings.

```
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,ab,c,323,123,acvd
4,db,c,323,123,acvd
```

I didn't want to over engineer the solution which i could PROBABLY use pandas / python.

It is also a very large file 5GB file, million + rows so isn't something i can open in excel.

Desired output would be to add the addition string or remove it i.e

```
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,dbc,323,123,acvd

4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,ab,323,123,acvd
4,db,323,123,acvd
```

Comment: Which comma is 'extra' in this example? What should row 3 and 4 be interpreted as?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since removing the extra field is an acceptable option for you:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $2, $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,ab,323,123,acvd
4,db,323,123,acvd
```

otherwise:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1, $2 (NF>5 ? $3 : ""), $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}' file
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,dbc,323,123,acvd
```

Answer (score 3):

This simple `awk` script would also do your job:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NF==6 {$2 = $2 $3; $3=""; sub(/,,/, ",")} 1' file.csv

4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,dbc,323,123,acvd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F',' -lane 'if ( @F > 5 ) { $_ = join ",", $F[0], "$F[1]$F[2]", @F[3..$#F]; } print;' in_file
```

Output:

```
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,abc,323,123,acvd
4,dbc,323,123,acvd
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F','` : Split into `@F` on comma, rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Prefect works - will give it read as well